# Javascript object calling value with dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, variables, object, dynamic

This is driving me insane. I am trying to grab an object in javascript using a dynamic variable. Static variables appear to work, yet I cant for the life of me see the difference between the static vars I put in and the dynamic vars.

My snippet below better illustrates the issue

```
console.log(itemId); //E2
console.log(typeof itemId); //string
console.log(typeof 'E2'); //string
console.log(ganttObject.items['E2']); //object [with data]
console.log(ganttObject.items[itemId]); //undefined
```

The weird thing is that I have extensively used dynamic calling of objects elsewhere in the script, but it is breaking here.

Tested in Safari & Chrome

Comment: does `console.log(itemId === 'E2')` evaluate to true? And are you absolutely sure nothing else is going on in your code?

Comment: @Andy no, it doesn't evaluate to true... What else can be the difference between two vars apart from type? It would all make sense if the first one `console.log(itemId)` was undefined or something other than 'E2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at last by tracing the value of `itemId` to the source. Turns out an edit in the html generation added a space after my id.

Moral of the story:

> Remember that trailing spaces won't show up on the console window

Answer (score 1):

Works for me in FF4: [image]

Are you sure you don't have a typo or something in your actual code?

Comment: Yea thats exactly what I would expect to see. Not so for my code. Those lines are a direct copy paste from where I was attempting to debug.

Comment: Ah, I found the answer at last by tracing the value of `itemId` to the source. Turns out an edit in the html generation added a space after my id.

Moral of the story: 

> Remember that trailing spaces won't show up on the console window